# Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException Error in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I Want Register user with modal And Rapid Authentication,I'm Using Ajax for sent data.
My Code is here:

```
 <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="mySignup">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="login-wrap">
            <div class="form text-center">
                <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
                <input type="email"  name="email" id="email"/>
                <input type="password" name="pw" id="password"/>
                <button id="SignUp">Signup</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        {{csrf_field()}}
    </div>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#SignUp').click(function (event) {
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var email = $('#email').val();
        var password =$('#password').val();
        $.post('/register',{
            'name' : name,
            'email' :email,
            'password':password,
            'token':$('input[name=_token]').val()
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

And In Web.php I'm Using this code:

```
Route::post('/register',[
'as'=> '',
'uses' => 'Auth\RegisterController@Register'
 ]);
```

But When I Want SignUp I give this Error message with 419 status code
`{message: "", exception: "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException",…}`
How I Can fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `token` to `_token` as laravel checks CSRF token in `_token`

```
'_token':$('input[name=_token]').val()
```

Comment: oh!Yes Tanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass token in header

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Add header on ajax call

```
headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
}
```